# Java basic Adjacency List

Tags: java

I made a very basic social network Java program. I was wondering if my design could be improved. I have 2 classes (+ 1 driver) : `Person` and `Graph`. I would like now to add a new method `hasAccount(Person person)` in the `Graph` class to check if a `Person` is on the graph. However, so far I don't have any data structure that stores every `Person` object added on the `Graph`. What would be the most efficient way to do it?

```
    public class Driver {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Graph facebook = new Graph();
        Person sara = new Person("sara");
        Person robert = new Person("robert");
        Person alex = new Person("alex");
        facebook.newFriendship(sara, robert);
        facebook.newFriendship(alex, sara);
        facebook.printFriends(sara);
        facebook.removeFriendship(sara, alex);
        facebook.printFriends(sara);
      }
    }

/*Class to represent friendships*/

    public class Graph {

        public void newFriendship(Person from, Person to) throws IllegalArgumentException{
            if(from == null || to == null){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("One of the account does not exits");
            }
            from.addFriend(to);
            to.addFriend(from);
        }

        public void removeFriendship(Person from, Person to) throws IllegalArgumentException{
            if(from == null || to == null){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("One of the account does not exits");}
            from.removeFriend(to);
            to.removeFriend(from);
        }

        public void printFriends(Person user){
            System.out.println(user.getFriendList());
        }
    }

/*Class to represent a User*/
    public class Person {
      private String name;
      private List<Person> friends;

      Person(String name){
        this.name = name;
        friends = new LinkedList();
      }

      public void addFriend(Person newFriend){
        this.friends.add(newFriend);
      }

      public List getFriendList(){
        List<String> friendList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Person friend : friends){
          friendList.add(friend.name);
        }
        return friendList;
      }

      public void removeFriend(Person toremove){
        friends.remove(toremove);
      }
    }
```

Comment: We can review your current code if it works, with your feature in mind. But this is code review, we don't do feature-requests.

Comment: (`Graph` does *not* `represent friendships` - and what business would it have to? The "driver" seems to be using `Graph` as a go-between. There is no way to *add Person objects on the Graph*. Under what circumstances do you think storage of person related data anywhere else (than with the person) tolerable?)

Answer (score 3):

`Graph` is a strange name for something designed to manipulate friendships.  As indicated by @greybeard in the comments, it doesn't really represent anything at the moment.

**print**

I hate seeing methods like `printFriends`  on classes.  They very rarely belong.  If you want to have the class provide a method/`toString` implementation that can be used by it's controller to write to the console / log / outputStream then that's one thing.  However, hardcoding `System.out.println` into classes really does limit their usefulness.

**control + error checking**

Is it valid to call `addFriendShip` twice for the same friends?  To Remove it twice?  What are you expecting in this scenario:

```
facebook.newFriendship(sara, robert);
facebook.newFriendship(robert, sara);
```

Sara ends up with two friends, both of whom are Robert.  This seems wrong.

**Friendship is a two way street**

This is nitpicky, but `newFriendShip` tells both supplied `Person`s that they have a new friend.  Having the parameter names `from` and `to` suggests a one directional, rather than two way relationship.

**List**

`getFriendList` returns a list of `String`s, unless there's a good reason not to, I'd set the return type appropriately, rather than just returning a basic `List`.  You should also consider using the `Stream` libraries, they can make your code more concise:

```
public List<String> getFriendList(){
    return friends.stream().map(f->f.name).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**Graph**

There are various structures that Graph could use to keep track of what `Person`s it knows about.  However, there isn't really enough information at the moment to suggest the correct method.  Some things to consider include, does Graph need to support adding and removing? If a Person is added, does the graph need to keep track of all that `Persons` friends as well?  How about their friends and so on?  What operations are you going to want `Graph` to support that will use the `Person`s it knows about?